# How can I select the 'title' attribute in an input tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors, title

Just like we have selectors like `("#id_name"),(".class_name") (":input_type")`..etc in jquery, how can I select the `title` attribute from an input tag?

Example: `< input type="abc" id="xyz" title="information" >`

I need a selector to select title value.

Comment: You should not use numeric ids.

Comment: Selectors match *elements*, not attribute values. Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What he wants to achieve is to get the title attribute.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$('input[title="information"]');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('input').attr('title');
```

@Alex is partially correct, you can have numbers but the id just cannot start with a number.

in your case you would selected the input like this.

```
$('#xyz').attr('title');
```

Comment: fo youre example: $('#xyz').attr('title');

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought that 'numeric' means 'contains numbers only'. :)

Comment: Ahh touche, Still good to know so I thought I'd throw it in there

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but here is your solution.

The var method can be very handy but you can do this directly via jQuery without var.

Say if you had a p (paragraph) with an id="p-2" and the title attribute value is RS4, and you like to colorize that paragraph in blue. You use the following.

```
$("#p-2[title='RS4']" ).css("color", "blue");
```

Another method if the title attribute value has the word RS4 contained in it in the case title="Audi RS4 is fast", then you can use ~= method.

```
$("#p-2[title~='RS4']" ).css("color", "blue");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var titleValue = $('#123').attr('title');
```

As Alex pointed out, you shouldn't use numeric ids.

Answer (score 1):

You use CSS attribute selectors.  For your example, it would be like this:

```
$('input[title="information"]')
```

See [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) for more information on selecting tags based on attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="abc" id="id_123" title="information" >
<script>
var title = $('#id_123').attr('title');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').attr('title')` or `$('input[title="whatever"])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query them by title using attribute selector

```
$('[type=abc]')
```

You can filter by attributes putting by using [ATTRIBUTE=VALUE].

If you want to return the attribute them use

```
$(SELECTOR).attr('type');
```

Also, it is not valid to start and Id value with a number, you should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow

```
$("[title|='Tomorrow']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var title = $("#xyz").attr("title");
// console.log(title) will print **information**;
```