# jQuery - check if the title attribute of an element is showing

Tags: jquery

If I have a element with a *title* attribute similar to this:

```
<p title="Ipsum"></p>
```

How can I run a function that tells me if the title is showing i.e. the tag popped up using jquery?

Edit: by pop up I mean when the user mouse overs the item so the title shows.

Comment: What does *"the tag popped up"* mean exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i select 'title' attribute in an input tag in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844678/how-can-i-select-title-attribute-in-an-input-tag-in-jquery)

Comment: There's no way to determine if the title is visible or not. Even if you went with using the hover event, you wouldn't know when the title disappeared.

Comment: Do you mean by <a href = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp">tooltip</a> you want to show title on hover over the html element it title exists??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` is a markup attribute and nothing more.

How a "tooltip" renders highly depends on the browser used, I guess... While it supposed to be commonly supported from all main browsers. The attribute does not create a DOM element which you could use some JS to test the visibility on it.

So the clear answer is NO. You just can't run any function that tells if the title is showing.

Comment: If that helps, you should look at [jQuery-UI tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), which creates a DOM element using the title attribute. And the tooltip is cuter and stylable. Really easy to set up... And from that, you could script something to detect when the tooltip is shown. ;)